# update git repository with apple script

Tags: terminal, applescript, git

I want to update my git Bitbucket online storage with apple script. This is the code that works in Terminal, but not when i run apple script.

```
cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git add -A
git commit -m fromAppleScript
git push
```

crafted into apple script:

```
        say "updating backup"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git add -A"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git commit -m fromAppleScript"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git push"
```

I am a bit puzzled why this code doesn't work. Can you help me out with this problem?

Comment: Do you have a shell script or commands that work when issued from within Terminal.app? Do you need help changing directory into your project and running `git push`?

Comment: I dont know how to do it, not even in Terminal.

Comment: `git` can be tricky to learn and debug. Consider mastering the steps you want via Terminal.app – with the help of [the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). [BitBucket support](https://bitbucket.org/support) provides a wealth of examples and workflows to try and to learn from. Once you trust that process, automating via AppleScript will be much easier.

Comment: You may need to separate the cd command from the git command in each line with a semi-colon: "cd ...; git ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using `git` as a file system back-up. Have you considered [`git-annex`](http://git-annex.branchable.com)?

## Learning `git`

`git` can be [tricky to learn and debug](https://xkcd.com/1597/). Consider mastering the steps you want via Terminal.app – with the help of [the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

[BitBucket support](https://bitbucket.org/support) provides a wealth of examples and workflows to try and to learn from. Once you trust that process, automating via AppleScript will be much easier.

## Fixing the Shell Script

To get you started, there are is a problem with the AppleScript. The script passed to **do shell script** will return an error:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git add -A"
```

Within these quotes you are issuing two commands: one to change directory, and the second to add files to git. These two commands need to be separated with a semi-colon:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects; git add -A"
```

A better approach still, would be to tie the commands together with `&&`. This will mean that if the first command fails, the second command is not performed. This approach deals with the problem of a missing or renamed directory:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects && git add -A"
```

Alternatively, to avoid working directory concerns try passing the full path to the `git` commands:

```
do shell script "git add -A '/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects'"
```